# Stop a method till condition is true

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app and I have a question:

Is there a way to pause a method until the user presses a view? I am considering doing something like this:

1. Make a boolean for my class called "wait".
2. When someone clicks on the view, it will change the boolean to true.
3. Finally, in the main method, do something like:

> ```
> while (!wait) 
> {
>  //do nothing
> }
> ```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: If you only want it to run after a View has been pressed, then why not just move that code to the onClick() or onTouch()?

Comment: you can start a timer and inside it make a check if(view pressed){your desired function} else(view not pressed){your desired function}

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are doing it like this...

```
boolean wait = false;

public void onClick(View v) {
       switch(v.getId())
       {
       case R.id.button1:
              doSomething();
              break;
       case R.id.button2:
              wait = true;
              break;
       }
}

public void doSomething() {
       //
       // Do Task 1
       //
       while(!wait) {}
       //
       // Do Task 2
       //
}
```

Instead, you can perform it like this...

```
boolean viewClicked = false;

public void onClick(View v) {
       switch(v.getId())
       {
       case R.id.button1:
              doSomething();
              break;
       case R.id.button2:
              viewClicked = true;
              doSomething();
              break;
       }
}

public void doSomething() {
       if(!viewClicked)
       {
              //
              // Do Task 1
              //
       }
       else
       {
              //
              // Do Task 2
              //
       }
}
```

I hope this helps. :)